# CUploadedFile::getInstance Always Returns Null on Uploaded File

Tags: forms, yii

I have built a form in YII and I need to process an uploaded file. I followed [this guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/265/file-uploads-in-cform-form-builder/), but I've stumbled upon an issue. `CUploadedFile::getInstance` always returns null.

Here's what I use. My model:

```
class AdditionalFieldFile extends CFormModel {

    public $uploadedFile;

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules() {
        return array(
            //note you wont need a safe rule here
            array('uploadedFile', 'file', 'allowEmpty' => true, 'types' => 'zip,doc,xls,ppt,jpg,gif,png,txt,docx,pptx,xlsx,pdf,csv,bmp'),
        );
    }

}
```

And handling the uploaded file in the controller on form submit:

```
$model = new AdditionalFieldFile();
$model->uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'field_'.$type_field.'['.$id_common.']');
```

And after that `$model->uploadedFile` is null for some reason.

Note that `$type_field` and `$id_common` come dynamically.

Also, the form has `'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'` so this is not the cause.

Comment: Could you show more code from your controller and your view?

Comment: are you sure that `'field_'.$type_field.'['.$id_common.']'`  generates proper name?

Comment: I think you should put `CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'uploadedFile');` but it depends on your view

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan Yes, I am sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a self-answer follows.

It turns out that I had to use the active file field in the view, using an instance of the class that extends `CFormModel` as a model.

Solution:

```
CHtml::activeFileField(new AdditionalFieldFile(), 'field_'.$type_field.'['.$id_common.']');
```